# Performing a foreach over an associative array of associative arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Suppose I have this setup:

```
var whatever = new Array();

whatever["a"] = new Array();
whatever["a"]["a"] = "test1";
whatever["a"]["b"] = "test2";

whatever["b"] = new Array();
whatever["b"]["a"] = "test3";
whatever["b"]["b"] = "test4";
```

And I attempt to iterate through it:

```
$.each(whatever, function(key, value) {
 $.each(value, function(subkey, subvalue) {
  //stuff with key, subkey, and subvalue here
 });
});
```

Yet the iteration fails, commenting out the nested foreach loop will allow the page to load, so that appears to be where the problem is.

Inside the first loop, I can do something like:

```
alert(value["a"]);
```

and receive the proper value, so it seems to be a "valid" array.  Where am I going wrong, since the nested loop is basically the same as the outer one?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this? In most cases an object is a better idea than nested arrays.

Comment: Javascript arrays are never associative and cannot have strings as keys. Javascript arrays are numerically indexed. What you're looking for is an object, which is a key-value store.

Comment: @deceze javascript arrays are just objects with numerical strings as keys, that said it's still better to use an object...

Comment: @Esailija Setting a string key on a Javascript Array object is not using the array properties of it. Yes, obviously you can do it, as the OP demonstrates, but it's not doing what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use objects instead of arrays.

```
var whatever = {};

whatever["a"] = {};
whatever["a"]["a"] = "test1";
whatever["a"]["b"] = "test2";

whatever["b"] = {};
whatever["b"]["a"] = "test3";
whatever["b"]["b"] = "test4";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QwT8W/

Comment: That was ridiculously simple.  Oops.  Thanks!