# how to get array values of keys stored in an object with "for in" loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I'd like to have an object with three properties, "zone1", "zone2", "zone3", each of which store an array of place names.  I would like to search for a match by iterating through the arrays to find a place name.
The following questions almost gets me there, but don't work for me because I am not using jQuery, and I want the value, not the key:

- [Performing a foreach over an associative array of associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269991/performing-a-foreach-over-an-associative-array-of-associative-arrays)
- [Getting a list of associative array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558981/iterating-through-list-of-keys-for-associative-array-in-json)

My code looks like this:

```
var zoneArray = {};
zoneArray["zone1"] = ["placeA", "placeB"];
zoneArray["zone2"] = ["placeC", "placeD"];

function getZone(place, zoneArray) {
    var zone;
    for (var key in zoneArray) {
        for(i = 0; i<key.length; i++) {
            if(key[i] == place) {
                zone = key;
                return zone;
            }
        }
    }

}
getZone("placeC", climateZoneArray);
```

Apparently however, "key[i]" is referring to letters of the zone names, like, "z" "o" "n" "e"

Could anybody please help me understand or best handle this situation in Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zoneArray[key]` to access the array.

```
for (var key in zoneArray) {
    var arr = zoneArray[key]
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == place) {
            zone = key;
            return zone;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for ... in` to iterate over an object's properties can lead to some pretty surprising results, especially if you're working in an environment where `Object.prototype` has been extended. This is because `for ... in` will iterate over an objects enumerable properties *and* the enumerable properties contained in that objects prototype chain. If this isn't what you want but you are going to use `for ... in` anyways, it's recommended to have a conditional statement at the top of the loop that checks that the property belongs to the object which is being iterated over. (`if (!foo.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;`). Luckily, there is `Object.keys()`. You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of an objects own enumerable properties, if you do this you can skip `hasOwnProperty` ugliness. Instead of iterating over the object you can iterate over an array of it's keys.

```
var collection = {
    zone1: ['placeA', 'placeB'],
    zone2: ['placeC', 'placeD']
};

function getZone(needle, collection) {
    var zones = Object.keys(collection),
        found;
    for (var i = 0, l = zones.length; i < l; i++) {
        found = collection[zones[i]].filter(function(place) {
            return needle == place;
        });
        if (found.length > 0) {
            return zones[i];
        }
    }
};

console.log(getZone('placeC', collection));
```

This is also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LRsWQ/1/) on jsfiddle.net

One last thing, be very careful when creating variables, in the inner `for` loop you created the variable `i` without using the `var` keyword. This resulted in `i` being bound to the global context, something you *really* want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks, Colin!  I really appreciate it.  I will take a closer look at these concepts :)